# Flask SocketIO: how to send message from backgroundtask

Tags: python, redis, flask-socketio

Please, I've been searching on this for 2 days already. I have to run some long functions that are on another files, so I use Redis Queue to run these functions on the background (works fine). But I want a confirmation on the client once the background task is done, so I use Flask SocketIO, to send messages.

Here's the example code. Let's say `test.py` is the main file. I want to execute the `task()` (from `utils.py`) on the background, and when its done, send a message to the client once `task()` is done.

test.py

```js
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit
from worker import conn
from redis import Redis
from rq import Queue
import time
from utils import task


app = Flask(__name__)

q = Queue(connection=Redis())


@ app.route("/update")
def update():
    job = q.enqueue(task)  # Running 'task' function in background
    return render_template("index_copy.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

utils.py

```js
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@socketio.on("message")
def task(msg):
    time.sleep(3)
    send(msg)  # (Socketio) Sending message to client once the background task is done
```

index_copy.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        const socket = io();
        socket.emit("message", "hello");
        socket.on('message', function (msg) {
            $("#mensaje").append("<p>" + msg + "</p>");
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You are enqueuing the Socket.IO handler function. Why are you doing that. The Socket.IO handlers run in the server. If you want to start a background function from this handler, then create a separate function and make it an RQ task.

Comment: @Miguel Thanks. Sorry I'm new to this. Let's say I create `task2()` just below my Socket.IO handler (`task()`) and run it in background using `q.enqueue(task2)`. Then how do I emit a message only after `task2()` is executed?

Comment: Add the emit at the bottom of task2. You will need to configure your application to use an external process as an emitter. See the documentation for details.